# What's all this uncommitted, reserved memory in my process?

Tags: windows, memory-management, sysinternals

I'm using VMMap from SysInternals to look at memory allocated by my Win32 C++ process on WinXP, and I see a bunch of allocations where portions of the allocated memory are reserved but not committed. As far as I can tell, from my reading and testing, all of the common memory allocators (e.g., malloc, new, LocalAlloc, GlobalAlloc) used in a C++ program always allocate fully committed blocks of memory.
Heaps are a common example of code that reserves memory but doesn't commit it until needed.  I suspect that some of these blocks are Windows/CRT heaps, but there appears to be more of these types of blocks than I would expect for heaps.  I see on the order of 30 of these blocks in my process, between 64k and 8MB in size, and I know that my code never intentionally calls VirtualAlloc to allocate reserved, uncommitted memory.

Here are a couple of examples from VMMap: http://www.flickr.com/photos/95123032@N00/5280550393/

What else would allocate such blocks of memory, where much of it is reserved but not committed?  Would it make sense that my process has 30 heaps?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's very nice to post the exact same question in two places at once. http://forum.sysinternals.com/uncommitted-reserved-memory-in-my-process_topic24690.html

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine.  Sysinternals is the author of the VMMap tool, so they may know why their tool is reporting such information.  Folks on StackOverflow may know what code would allocate memory in such patterns.  Two different audiences who may not be reading both forums.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out - it's the CRT heap that gets allocated by calls to `malloc`.  If you allocate a large chunk of memory (e.g., 2 MB) using `malloc`, it allocates a single committed block of memory.  But if you allocate smaller chunks (say 177kb), then it will reserve a 1 MB chunk of memory, but only commit approximately what you asked for (e.g., 184kb for my 177kb request).

When you free that small chunk, that larger 1 MB chunk is not returned to the OS.  Everything but 4k is uncommitted, but the full 1 MB is still reserved.  If you then call `malloc` again, it will attempt to use that 1 MB chunk to satisfy your request.  If it can't satisfy your request with the memory that it's already reserved, it will allocate a new chunk of memory that's twice the previous allocation (in my case it went from 1 MB to 2 MB).  I'm not sure if this pattern of doubling continues or not.

To actually return your freed memory to the OS, you can call `_heapmin`.  I would think that this would make a future large allocation more likely to succeed, but it would all depend on memory fragmentation, and perhaps heapmin already gets called if an allocation fails (?), I'm not sure.  There would also be a performance hit since heapmin would release the memory (taking time) and malloc would then need to re-allocate it from the OS when needed again.  This information is for Windows/32 XP, your mileage may vary.

UPDATE: In my testing, heapmin did absolutely nothing. And the malloc heap is only used for blocks that are less than 512kb.  Even if there are MBs of contiguous free space in the malloc heap, it will not use it for requests over 512kb. In my case, this freed, unused, yet reserved malloc memory chewed up huge parts of my process' 2GB address space, eventually leading to memory allocation failures.  And since heapmin doesn't return the memory to the OS, I haven't found any solution to this problem, other than restarting my process or writing my own memory manager.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a thread is created in your application a certain (configurable) amount of memory will be reserved in the address space for the call stack of the thread. There's no need to commit all the reserved memory unless your thread is actually going to need all of that memory. So only a portion needs to be committed.

If more than the committed amount of memory is required, it will be possible to obtain more system memory.

The practical consideration is that the reserved memory is a hard limit on the stack size that reduces address space available to the application. However, by only committing a portion of the reserve, we don't have to consume the same amount of memory from the system until needed.

Therefore it is possible for each thread to have a portion of reserved uncommitted memory. I'm unsure what the page type will be in those cases.

Comment: So Does it mean that whenever there is for example 10 threads created by Application, OS "Reserves" some memory (~4KB)for each thread in advance for threads to use in future?

Answer (score 0):

Could they be the DLLs loaded into your process?  DLLs (and the executable) are memory mapped into the process address space.  I believe this initially just reserves space.  The space is backed by the files themselves (at least initially) rather than the pagefile.

Only the code that's actually touched gets paged in.  If I understand the terminology correctly, that's when it's committed.

You could confirm this by running your application in a debugger and looking at the modules that are loaded and comparing their locations and sizes to what you see in VMMap.

Comment: DLLs are listed separately in VMMap as either IMAGE or MAPPED FILE.  These allocations are shown as PRIVATE memory, so they're not DLLs.