# The maximum malloc space in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, malloc

I am writing a simulation program, and I define a struct Node, of about 544 bytes. In the program I need to `malloc` millions of nodes. Each time when the maximum number reaches almost 3 million,

```
newnode=malloc(Node）
```

will return NULL. But this just takes about 250MB of memory. Can someone tell me why this happens and how to solve this problem?

Comment: maybe because your program heap size is limited?

Comment: 64- or 32-bit compiler? OS 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: Looks like the heap behaviour described in the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186079/the-maximum-malloc-space-for-visula-studio-c). The only solution appears to be to roll your own memory allocator.

Comment: 3 * 10^6 * 544 / 1024^2 = 1556.3964843750

Comment: @TonyD. Doh! Thanks for pointing that out. [Here's the real link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503276/whats-all-this-uncommitted-reserved-memory-in-my-process). Perhaps the OP can run VMMap and tell us if he sees large amounts of uncommitted but reserved memory in his process at the point of failure.

Comment: the system for my computer is Windows 7 64-bits